# Apple Hypervisor is completely broken on MacOS Big Sur beta 11.0.1

Tags: c, swift, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

I am trying to make a basic command-line tool that makes a VM and runs something using Apple Hypervisor.

When I try to run `hv_vm_create(HV_VM_DEFAULT)` it gives me an error code -85377023.

I tried enforcing App Sandbox and setting the entitlement accordingly for the Big Sur compile target, and now I am getting this output in the console:

```
Killed
```

From what I understand from this, this is AMFI killing my process. Is this a bug or my problem?

When I decided to go down the rabbit hole, I found that in the MacOS Big Sur 11.0.1 beta release notes, they **deprecated** `hv_vm_run(_:)`, while the API documentation says that this function is in beta.

I didn't go as far as disabling AMFI with a kernel flag, but I am almost certain that this is not expected behavior. And that, no matter what, `hv_vm_run(_:)` can **never** be deprecated OR be in beta. I am sure that this function existed well before Big Sur.

If anyone can help me with this or just give a response, please do. Do not keep me in darkness as I don't want to waste time on something which is potentially broken.

Thank you.

P.S: I know that there is already a thread in the Apple Developer forums, I am the one who posted it. Though, no one is answering there because their community is not even close to being as large as Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

This error code you're seeing is just a poor UX on the macOS side: what it's really trying to communicate is that the [`com.apple.security.hypervisor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_hypervisor) entitlement is missing.

If you're using Xcode, you can add it like that:

1. Press <kbd>⌘N</kbd> and create a new **Property List** file.
2. Add a new property with the key `com.apple.security.hypervisor` and a boolean value set to `YES`.
3. Go to **Project** → **Target** → **Build Settings** → **Signing** → **Code Signing Entitlements** and make sure it uses your newly created entitlements file.

Alternatively, you can use command line:

```sh
codesign -s - --entitlements app.entitlements --force path/to/your/binary
```

Where `app.entitlements` contents is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.hypervisor</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The other way you to solve this is to simply set the **Deployment Target** to `10.13` in the Xcode's settings (props to [Alexander Pinske](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit/issues/300#issuecomment-729672267)):

[image: setting Xcode deployment target in the General tab]

The reason this works is most likely due to backwards-compatibility, so bear in mind that this might change in the future macOS releases, or, perhaps, on newly introduced platforms like Apple Silicon.